# Angular 4 router not working with relative path

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Angular 4 router works with absolute path like

```
loadChildren: 'app/dummy/dummy.module#DummyModule' }
```

But not working with following

```
 loadChildren: '../dummy/dummy.module#DummyModule' }
```

' PS:-I want to be worked with relative path How to achieve this in angular router

Comment: It should work if your relative path is correct corresponds to the file you are referring from.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `loadChildren: () =>`

I have create a demo on [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-hide-navigation-side-bar-in-login-page-in-angular-4-proj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

```
import { DummyModule } from './dummy/dummy.module';

{ path: 'path', loadChildren: () => DummyModule }
```

Comment: what is diff between 
loadChildren:()=>
And 
loadChildren:

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in your code as below. Just remove one dot.

`loadChildren: './dummy/dummy.module#DummyModule' }`

This will help you.

Comment: Although My relative path is ./ because it is at source